# Prefilled data in facebook web dialog

Tags: ios, facebook, deprecated

Is there any way i can prefill any string in FBWebDialog? Any workaround would do,I am aware facebook has deprecated the message parameter from their sdk.

My scenario is user clicks on a facebook contact
FBWebDialog opens and then the message gets prefilled with some text instead of a blank textfield.

any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okay, from the comments it sounds like you want to post on the user's wall. Here is a method that is available in the [FB SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/) that pulls up a share dialog within your app and supports pre filled text

```
[FBDialogs presentOSIntegratedShareDialogModallyFrom:self initialText:@"Initial text" image:nil url:nil handler:nil];
```

Example with pre filled text:

[image: Screenshot of share with pre filled text]

---

Which type of dialog are you opening? (Sounds like the Send dialog, if you want to send a Facebook message.)

I do not think it is possible to even send a message directly to a user from iOS. When performing the following I get the error "This dialog is not available on this device"

```
[FBWebDialogs presentDialogModallyWithSession:nil dialog:@"send" parameters ...
```

iOS FB SDK [WebDialog reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBWebDialogs) shows the following methods:

```
+ presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:message:title:parameters:handler:
+ presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:message:title:parameters:handler:friendCache:
```

Those seem to support pre-populating the message field. They only support apprequests though (not messages) and whether the message is even attached is a bit unknown (all I saw when testing was "User wants you to try App", not the actual string I set).

The javascript API (which could maybe be pulled up in a webview?) doesn't have a parameter to set the message probably because the [Send dialog documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/) says:

> Facebook messages are a channel for person-to-person communication,
>   and not for apps to send messages, or encourage people to spam their
>   friends.

If you just want to post a message/share then you can use a [share sheet](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios-6/) which looks to support an initial message:

```
[FBNativeDialogs presentShareDialogModallyFrom:self initialText:@"My text to share" ...
```

Comment: Have a look at Happy B'day App,it seems to post to on users wall with a prepopulated message.I dont understand how

Comment: Oh, okay, yeah, post on wall is different then send a message to a specific user. Is that a sample app or app store?

Comment: It is basically an Appstore app

Comment: Updated above with instructions for posting to the wall with example screenshot. Share a link or screenshot of the Happy B'day App if you are looking for something else.

Comment: The above dialog lets the user to post a status update and not on the users wall.
"Presents a dialog that allows the user to share a status update that may include text, images, or URLs."
I want to post a prefilled text message on friends wall.

Comment: My understanding is "The Wall" no longer exists. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_features#Wall